# How to get 1. Multiple Ids 2. Multiple Row Values - Play - Form.form()?

Tags: playframework

There are two use cases.

1. UI will send list of ids as string values i.e just list of employee ids to be 
   removed or deleted.
2. UI will send list of objects i.e multiple row values - capturing table row 
   values for update

   ```
   Form<List<String>> form = Form.form(......);
   Form<List<EmployeeVo>> form = Form.form(......);
   ```

I'm not sure what is full valid syntax or valid values needs to be given inside form(.....) for the above two use cases.

How to retrieve the values for the above 2 use cases.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are retrieved using the following

Map formValues = play.mvc.Controller.request().body().asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded();

override = Boolean.valueOf(formValues.get("data1")[0]);